# Check number against all ranges in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have to check specific numbers from file1 against all ranges from file2.

cat file1

20**00000000000328051779**00000000000000000000922820669 xx
20**00000000000228051777**00000000000000000000922820669 xx
20**00000000000228051813**00000000000000000000922820669 xx

cat file2

```
 228051777, 228051779
 228051811, 228051814
 228051817, 228051817
```

output

20**00000000000228051777**00000000000000000000922820669 xx
20**00000000000228051813**00000000000000000000922820669 xx

This is my code so far. Got the right output but it is too slow from reading thousands of records.

```
   #segregate records
awk -F', +' '
  # 1st pass (fileB): read the lower and upper range bounds
 FNR==NR { lbs[++count] = $1+0; ubs[count] = $2+0; next }
  # 2nd pass (FILES): check each line against all ranges.
 { 
   for(i=1;i<=count;++i) {
   anum=substr($1,3,22); sub(/^0+/, "", anum)
    if (anum+0 >= lbs[i] && anum+0 <= ubs[i]) { print; next }
   }
 }
' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F', *' 'NR == FNR {
   lb[++i] = $1;
   ub[i] = $2;
   next
} {
   anum = substr($1,3,20)+0;
   for(k=1; k<=i; k++)
      if (anum >= lb[k] && anum <= ub[k])
         print
}' file2 file1

200000000000022805177700000000000000000000922820669 xx
200000000000022805181300000000000000000000922820669 xx
```

Comment: it works, but when I added a record above it doesn't print an output. --> **200000000000022008909400000000000000000000923678826400**

Comment: It works with the given input. If input has changed then you should edit the question and show new input data.

Comment: Yes, but still too lengthy in processing thousands of records like the code I've provided..

Comment: You should only be concerned about overall efficiency of the script. Above script can be made a one line also.